# How to add a cross fade to UI tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, fade

Hi I copy question from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-add-a-cross-fade-to-ui-tabs, because I have same question.

Hi all

I have set up a tabbed interface using standard UI tab code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#tabbedArea").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } }).tabs('rotate', 6000, 'true')
});
</script>
```

At the moment the tab that is one display fades out, leaving a white space before the next tab appears.

What I would like to happen is as tab1 fades out, tab 2 fades in - creating a cross fade.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350666/jquery-ui-tabs-available-fx-options

Comment: the question not answer proper - its still white between change and not proper cross-fade. Soo my question still not answered

Answer (score 6):

I think Jquery UI can't do this by default. However jQuery Tabs UI [comes with a event "show"](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show), where you can write some custom code to toggle the tabs yourself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({

        show: function(event, ui) {

            var lastOpenedPanel = $(this).data("lastOpenedPanel");

            if (!$(this).data("topPositionTab")) {
                $(this).data("topPositionTab", $(ui.panel).position().top)
            }         

            //Dont use the builtin fx effects. This will fade in/out both tabs, we dont want that
            //Fadein the new tab yourself            
            $(ui.panel).hide().fadeIn(500);

            if (lastOpenedPanel) {

                // 1. Show the previous opened tab by removing the jQuery UI class
                // 2. Make the tab temporary position:absolute so the two tabs will overlap
                // 3. Set topposition so they will overlap if you go from tab 1 to tab 0
                // 4. Remove position:absolute after animation
                lastOpenedPanel
                    .toggleClass("ui-tabs-hide")
                    .css("position", "absolute")
                    .css("top", $(this).data("topPositionTab") + "px")
                    .fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $(this)
                        .css("position", "");
                    });

            }

            //Saving the last tab has been opened
            $(this).data("lastOpenedPanel", $(ui.panel));

        }

    });
});
```

Live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/FFTzU/7/

Comment: Is it possible to make it compatible with the latest versions of jQuery (1.10.1) and jQuery UI (1.10.3)?

Answer (score 2):

Great answer Richard just what I needed! I had a thought that your solution calls 2 animations (fade out and fade in) which on my js-heavy page was looking a little less than smooth. I have edited your solution slightly to use the z-index and 1 fade. This makes things a bit smoother for me at least.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  show: function(event, ui) {
    var lastOpenedPanel = $(this).data("lastOpenedPanel");
    if (!$(this).data("topPositionTab")) {
        $(this).data("topPositionTab", $(ui.panel).position().top)
    }
    // do crossfade of tabs
    $(ui.panel).hide().css('z-index', 2).fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $(this).css('z-index', '');
      if (lastOpenedPanel) 
      {
        lastOpenedPanel
          .toggleClass("ui-tabs-hide")
          .hide();
      }
    });

    $(this).data("lastOpenedPanel", $(ui.panel));
  } 
}).tabs('rotate', 3000);
```

I added the rotate at the end since this makes for quite a nice slideshow!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the above answers worked for an earlier version of jQuery UI, but the `show` and `hide` properties do not work this way currently. The effect can be achieved using `beforeActivate`:

```
$("#tabbedArea").tabs({
    hide: 1000,
    beforeActivate: function(event, ui){
        ui.newPanel.css('zIndex', 1).fadeIn(1000, function(){
            $(this).css('zIndex', '');
        });
    }
});
```

Note the tab panels must be positioned absolutely.